# What is the right term for a "transferred" force?

Tags: translation, terminology

Imagine you pull a rope grabbing it with your hands. What happens is, that due to friction you can "transfer" a force onto the rope. This force is actually limited to a maximum force which can be "transfered", dependent on the friction coefficient. In case this maximum force is exceeded the rope will slip out of your hands.

Now how is this force called? Is it the

- transmittable force
- transferable force
- transfusible/-fusive force
- transmissible/-missive force
- assignable force maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is the;

> Applied Force

It is the force that you applied on the rope. When your hands slip away it is because the applied force is greater than the opposing frictional force.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Lewis, this would definitely be the `Applied Force` that you are looking for, the applied force becomes transferable onto the rope so Transferable was your closest guess. All the other options are invalid.